# Simple proof that Lisp expresses all computable list functions

Tags: computability, programming-languages, turing-completeness, lisp

Given computable function $f : LispTerm \rightarrow LispTerm$ is it possible to implement it in Lisp?

The $LispTerm$ is any term that is constructed using `cons`, `nil` and `set-car!`, `set-cdr!` (because it can be cyclic).

Of course Lisp is Turing-Complete, but that does not immediately imply an answer because Lisp would be Turing-Complete even if it didn't have `cons` without which we would not be able to construct a new $LispTerm$, and thus would not be able to implement all transformations. To be clear: Lisp interpreter reads not an "encoded version" of a $LispTerm$, such as a string representation of it, but literally the term itself, so that if there were no `car` operation in Lisp, then we would never be able to access first element of a $LispTerm$.

I am looking for a simple proof, or a reference, if it is a known fact.
A proof that is **probably too hard** is one that requires to convert terms to natural numbers, then use the fact that on numbers Lisp is Turing-Complete, and then convert numbers back to terms. Unless there is an obvious way of converting cyclic terms to numbers and especially the other way.

### Computability in relation to $LispTerm$s

To say that function $f$ is computable means that there exists a structure preserving map $h$ between $LispTerm$s and binary strings (inputs of Turing Machines) such that if we use the mapping on $f$ resulting in a function $g : \{0, 1\}^* \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^*$, then $g$ is computable.
The map $h$ is structure preserving iff $\forall x, \forall y, f(x) = y \iff g(h(x)) = h(y)$.

### Example $LispTerm$s

Objects like `(cons nil nil)` and `(cons (cons nil nil) nil)` are $LispTerm$s that can be constructed by the identical Lisp code.
There are also cyclic terms. A cyclic term `x` = `(cons x nil)` could be constructed with the following Lisp code:

```lisp
(define x (cons nil nil))
(set-car! x x)
```

Formally, $LispTerm$s are ordered graphs of degree 2, or functions of type $f : V \rightarrow V^2$, where $V$ is the set of nodes.

Function `car` returns first element of a $LispTerm$, and `cdr` returns the second element.

Comment: What's your definition of computable function? There are no $LispTerm$ in Turing machine.

Comment: @Dmitry I added my understanding to the question, thanks for asking. My definition of computability is the same as in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88610/defining-computable-functions-on-arbitrary-sets?rq=1 for example.

Comment: If I understood the meaning of these Lisp functions correctly, this is not the definition you want. First, consider only the following subset of terms: lists whose elements are either `[]` or `nil`. For such lists, there exists a natural mapping to/from natural numbers, and hence you can naturally encode Turing machines using this set of terms. Lisp can't solve Halting problem, but it's possible according to your definition: you select the mapping $f$ so that $f(x)$ is odd if the Turing machine halts, and even if it doesn't halt. $g$ simply extract the last bit.

Comment: Why do you say that doing the proof via encoding with numbers is too hard? Also, you need to fix the definition of computable function, it's non-sensical (see Dimitry's remark).

Comment: @Dmitry, you are right, my bad. I fixed the definition of computability by adding the assumption that the mapping has to be structure preserving, which rules out the mapping that your proof uses.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think it's too hard because it requires to implement the encoding in lisp, and since our terms are graphs, not even trees, it not obvious how to handle them. I was hoping for a simple argument of type "since we can construct and deconstruct any LispTerm (proof of this must be simple), and the language is Turing-complete even without LispTerms, then surely it's Turing-complete on the terms".

(Fixed the non-sensical definition.)

Comment: @prog, I'm not sure I understand why your definition rules out my example.

Comment: @Dmitry, it's because inputs/outputs of $f$ now have to agree with those of $g$. Lets say that we encode `[]` as 1 and `nil` as 0. Then say that machine encoded as list `([] nil nil [] nil)` halts, so $f$ must return `[]` here. But the last bit, returned by $g$ is 0, whichs says that this machine should not halt. Because functions return different results, the restriction on $h$ is violated: $f($`([] nil nil [] nil)`$) = $`[]`$ \iff g((1 0 0 1 0)) = 1$ is false. Do you agree?

Comment: I see, I think you are correct. I don't have time right now to check, but I think your definition doesn't prevent you from solving the halting problem: again the mapping $h$ solves the Halting problem, just in a more convoluted way.